# Charset windows-1251 in Alamofire request?

Tags: swift, character-encoding, alamofire, cp1251

Help, server that I use work only with charset windows-1251. But Alamofire use utf8. I try to change headers, but it's not work for me.
How use Alamofire with another charset, not utf8?

Comment: Watching the [source code of Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), in most part needing String.Encoding, utf8 is hard-coded. That is reasonable as UTF-8 is the only standard in modern networking. If you want to work with legacy servers which uses windows-1251, you may need to avoid using Alamofire or make your own version of Alamofire modifying the source code. I strongly recommend to update your server.

Comment: Thanks! At another forum people help me with it. https://toster.ru/q/544601. I hope, in future, I can do it with Alamofire. But now I need to use URLSession.